# How to get size() of initialized ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I have some code similar to this:

```
ArrayList<SomeType> toGetSizeOf = new ArrayList<SomeType>();
int size = toGetSizeOf.size();
```

However, the second line is giving me a NullPointerException. Is there some way to avoid this, to basically tell if the ArrayList has been initialized but has not as of yet had anything added to it yet? (I have an `if`/`else` statement dependent on this).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a second view to your code, you should get size = 0

Comment: That shouldn't be giving you a NullPointerException.  Please construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates this.

Comment: Please show us some more lines of your code.That can't give you nullpointer exception

Comment: My apologies, for some reason when I run test cases they are coming out correct (size = 0), however, in the application I am developing, I am getting a NullPointerException at the line in my code `int stuff2 = stuff.size();` (not the actual names of my variables, just lines I put in to help myself debug).

Comment: I apologize, as multiple people have written, I finally managed to see that the referred to ArrayList is in fact null, though I must yet discover why...thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think perhaps something else is wrong in your code.

The following works fine:

```
ArrayList<String> toGetSizeOf = new ArrayList<String>();
int size = toGetSizeOf.size();
System.out.println(size);
```

Which gives 0.

Debug your code and check what is actually null. I suspect it's your toGetSizeOf.

Answer (score 0):

If you having issues with a `NullPointerException` then you should be checking for it first

You could use...

```
int size = 0;
if (toGetSizeOf != null) {
    size = toGetSizeOf.size();
}
```

or...

```
int size = toGetSizeOf == null ? 0 : toGetSizeOf.size();
```

You could also use [`ArrayList#isEmpty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#isEmpty%28%29) which returns a `boolean` `true`, if the list is empty (`size == 0`) or `false` if it is not, depending on your needs